# Prefix file not working with tests

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest

When I set up my project initially I moved the files around a bit to my liking. I fixed my Info.plist file to work with my builds (Debug, Beta, Release). It all works. But now I'm trying to write my tests and it keeps failing.

It gives me this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/path/to/apps/ios/App/App/App-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

The path it is referring to does not exist. I cannot find any mention to that path either. So is there a way I can disable the Prefix PCH file from being used while testing?

Comment: If you click on your prefix file, and look at "Identity and Type" in the right hand sidebar menu, does the "Location' and "Full Path" make sense?